# Color shift FFmpeg raw RGBA images to YUV format

Tags: ffmpeg, colorspace

I have a list of raw bitmap in rgba format, captured with an openGL frameBuffer.
I want to export them in a video, currently i am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 30 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1920x1018 -i - -threads 0 -y -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 8000K -vf vflip,drawbox=10:20:200:60:red@1:t=fill result.mp4
```

When I open the output video in different viewers (vlc, windows media player), the resulting color are shifted and appears more green.

For example I draw a solid red rectangle (255, 0, 0) got translated to (255, 24, 0)

I have played with pix_fmt and the format filter with no result.

[image]

Comment: *got translated to* --> measured, how?

Comment: screen capture and paint's color Picker, but it's visible in the video. The player might be the problem i try 2 of them, if you know a way to keep the original pixel value just for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

In the end I add to use the following options and tell ffmpeg wich colorSpace i am using and how to decode it to display on screen.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 30 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1920x1017 -i - -threads 0 -y -c:v libopenh264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -b:v 8000K -vf vflip,scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 output.mp4
```